# React - Custom hook throws error when using it

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've got a question. I'm sure it is a simple one, but actually I can't figure out, what the issue is.
I have this custom hook:

```
const goodsSetupWizardController = (props) => {
    const [product, setProduct] = useState(props.product);

    const getComponent = (step) => {
        //...
    };

    const isNextButtonDisabled = (step) => {
        //...
    };

    const needsNextStepToBeSkipped = (direction) => {
        //...
    };

    return {
        getComponent,
        isNextButtonDisabled,
        needsNextStepToBeSkipped
    };
}

export default goodsSetupWizardController;
```

...but when I want to use it, I get this error ("...goodsSetupWizardController is not a function"). Here is the full error:

```
> react-dom.development.js?ac89:22839 Uncaught TypeError: (0 ,
> _components_managementInterface_shop_tabs_productSetupWizard_setups_goodsSetupWizard_controller__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.goodsSetupWizardController)
> is not a function
>     at getProductTypeSetupWizard (productSetup.factory.js?cf3c:21:53)
>     at eval (productSetupWizard.component.js?532a:184:60)
>     at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js?ac89:23150:1)
>     at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js?ac89:24926:1)
>     at commitPassiveMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js?ac89:24891:1)
>     at commitPassiveMountEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js?ac89:24878:1)
>     at commitPassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js?ac89:24866:1)
>     at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js?ac89:27039:1)
>     at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js?ac89:26984:1)
>     at commitRootImpl (react-dom.development.js?ac89:26935:1)
```

I'm using it this way:

```
import goodsSetupWizardController from '../components/managementInterface/shop/tabs/productSetupWizard/setups/goodsSetupWizard.controller';

export function getProductTypeSetupWizard(productTypeId, step, product = null) {
    //...
    switch(parseInt(productTypeId)) {
        case 1:
            // this is where the error is thrown:
            const controller = goodsSetupWizardController({ product: product, step: step });
    }
    //...
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you share the line of code which you have imported `goodsSetupWizardController` in your component?

Comment: It exactly this line, where the error is thrown: `const controller = goodsSetupWizardController({ product: product, step: step });`

Comment: Looks like transpiler/bundler problem. Where did you get `goodsSetupWizardController` from in the component's containing file? Something like `import goodsSetupWizardController from "./path/to/some/other/file.js"`? We need to see this line.

Comment: Yeah, as you wrote. It is like this in the same file of method `getProductTypeSetupWizard`: `import goodsSetupWizardController from '../components/managementInterface/shop/tabs/productSetupWizard/setups/goodsSetupWizard.controller';`

Comment: Right after this line, try `console.log(goodsSetupWizardController)` and show the result. My guess is that, it's gonna be an object like `{ default: function goodsSetupWizardController() {...} }`

Comment: This is the result: `goodsSetupWizardController(props) {
  var _useState = (0,react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.useState)(props.product),
      _useState2 = _slicedToArray(_useState, 2),
      product = _useState2[0],
 …`

Comment: That's wierd. Can you confirm `console.log(typeof goodsSetupWizardController === 'function')`?

Comment: The result is as expected `true`

Comment: Try to capitalize `const GoodsSetupWizardController = () = {}`.

Comment: Instead of `export default` try named export like `export { goodsSetupWizardController }`. And in `productSetup.factory.js`, use named import accordingly. `import { goodsSetupWizardController } from "..."`

Comment: One thing I can tell from the compiled code shown in error msg `long_prefix__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.goodsSetupWizardController` this pattern looks like a named import to me. If it's a default import it probably would be `long_prefix__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default` I dono where it goes wrong yet.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few rules on how we can use hooks (including custom hooks) in React. Here it mostly concerns two of them:

1. `hooks` in React can not or should not be used inside control flow or conditional statements like `if/else`, `switch cases`, `loops`. The reason is, on every, render the hook needs to run like it did in the previous render (the order needs to remain the same).
2. ***`hooks`
   can be called only inside of a functional component***. `getProductTypeSetupWizard` where you are trying to use your custom hook is just a normal js function.

For eg.:

```js
// this is bad
if(today === 'monday'){
  useCustomHook(() => {
    // your code here
  }, [...deps]);
}

// do this instead
useCustomHook(() => {
  if(today === 'monday'){
    // your code here
  }
}, [...deps]);

// Usages:

// this is bad
const normalFunction = (...args) => {
 const data = useCutomHook();

 // your code here doesn't return a JSX element
 return data.value;
}

// Do this instead
const Component = (props) => {
 const data = useCutomHook();
 
 // returns JSX element
return (<div>{data.value}</div>);
}
```

By convention custom hooks are named with `use` prefix, for eg.: `useGoodsSetupWizardController`.

More about it here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#explanation.

Comment: Yeah good point. But that doesn't explain the problem OP has on his plate.

Comment: @hackape, right. I missed that point. It's because hooks can only be called inside a `functional component` and the OP is trying to call it inside of a normal function. I will update my answer.

Comment: @BikramKarki Thanks for your answer. Many good hints in there. I will have a look at this issue later and let you know, if it helped. But one question: You wrote that hooks should not be used inside control flow or conditional statements. If I want to differiate, which hook to be used, how can I do that then? In my case I thought I can use the factory pattern, to differentiate between the used hook. But that won't work then, if got you right.

Comment: I read your answer again. You wrote, that "hooks can be called only inside of a functional component" and your example says, that I should return a JSX component. But I don't want to return a JSX component. I only want to return methods without UI. One of these methods is returning a JSX component then. Is there really no way to let React only return methods for other components without having a UI?